# What happens when a GPL licence is changed to a LGPL?

Tags: gpl, relicensing, lgpl

I'm using an open source library under GPL in a closed source project. If the libraries license changes from GPL to LGPL, does it mean the previous code (written when the library was GPL) should be made open source?

Comment: Presumably the previous code written under GPL *already is* open source? I don't understand this question; can you add more details?

Comment: @what if I'm using an open source library under GPL in a closed source project and the libraries license changes from GPL to LGPL

Comment: *"what if I'm using an open source library under GPL in a closed source project*" -- you cannot distribute GPL code in a project that is not GPL-licensed, so if you're distributing it, you were violating the GPL and may have *stopped* violating the GPL by switching to the LGPL. If you're not distributing it, absolutely nothing changes, because the GPL family of licenses only impact distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GPL is already an open source license.

But if you relicense a project (and a license change from GPL to LGPL [needs the permission of all contributors](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-to-relicense-a-project), I assume that this is given) does not change the license on the old code. So the previous code is still available under the GPL, nothing changes in that regard.