# How can i change the license of an open source project?

Tags: relicensing, attribution

What is the good way to change the license of an opensource project?

- I guess it depends of the agreements of the contributors

  - Do i need 100% approval?
  - What if one contributor disagree or one contributor didn't answer?
- What about versions?

  - If change happens at version X, does it apply for previous versions?
- Where should it be mentioned? On homepage at least. Also in the code?

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne I would be inclined to agree, but it should be made known that the OP closed his own question as a duplicate, because the Community user is on the list of those who voted to close.